# Converter API JSon PHP para C#

Tags: php, c#, json

Olá, estou tendo dificuldade em converter uma API PHP para ser usada no C#, consigo realizar a conexão com a API mas não consigo enviar dados, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue API em PHP:

```
$process = curl_init("URL API");
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USUARIO:SENHA");
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        "establishment" => $establishment,
        "username" => $usuario,
        "password" => $senha,
        "name" => $nome,
        "email" => $email,
        "cpf" => $cpf,
        "login_expiration" => $expirarLogin,
        "profile_id" => $perfil
    ));

    if(json_decode(curl_exec($process)) === false){
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Segue o que consegui fazer até agora usando o C#:

```
using RestSharp;

var cookie = new CookieContainer();
var client = new RestClient("URL API") {
  Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("USUARIO", "SENHA"),
    CookieContainer = cookie
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
//var process = new RestClient(Method.POST);
//request.AddParameter(""", "projectID=729-11230-1", ParameterType.RequestBody);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "name=Example backlog item 1", ParameterType.RequestBody);

//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "establishment=sesc_new", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "username=user", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "password=senha", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "name=Teste API Sharp", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "email=email", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "cpf=cpf", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "login_expiration=2018-07-20 23:59:59", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
//request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "profile_id=4080", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
```

Consigo realizar a conexão, mas agora não sei como enviar as informações para a API a partir do C#.

[image: Mensagem de retorno da API ao conectar com o C#]

Comment: Pelo content que você está printando, o c# já está se comunicando com a API. E retornando os dados corretamente. Agora você só precisa tratar o retorno.

Comment: Poie é, só que que queria fazer o contrario, ao invés de retornar algo de lá, eu queria enviar algo para lá. Isso que não estou conseguindo, porque na API é de envio e não retorno.